# Run the rails server and protrator using gulp task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gulp, protractor

I have to run the rails server and protractor using single command. So, I choose to used the gulp task and below is my gulp file:

```
'use strict';

 var gulp = require('gulp');
 var shell = require('gulp-shell');
 var runSequence = require('run-sequence');
 var protractor = require('gulp-protractor').protractor
 var exec = require('child_process').exec;  

  gulp.task('start-server',function(cb){
    exec('RAILS_ENV=test rails s -p 8000 -P 42324',function(err,stdout,stderr){
      console.log(stdout);
      console.log(stderr);
      cb(err);
    });
    exec('start-protractor',function(err,stdout,stderr){
      'protractor protractor.conf.js'
    });
  });

  gulp.task('rails-kill',shell.task([
    "kill 'cat ../tmp/pids/server.pid'"
  ]));

  gulp.task('e2e-test', function(){
    runSequence('start-server','rails-kill')
  });

  gulp.task('default',['e2e-test']);
```

When I run the gulp in the terminal rails server started but never run the protractor.Below is terminal output

```
Sab-MacBook-Pro:spec sab$ gulp
[14:12:41] Using gulpfile ~/RubymineProjects/myproject/spec/gulpfile.js
[14:12:41] Starting 'e2e-test'...
[14:12:41] Starting 'start-server'...
[14:12:41] Finished 'e2e-test' after 7.15 ms
[14:12:41] Starting 'default'...
[14:12:41] Finished 'default' after 9.69 μs
```

Any help will be really appreciated.

Thanks

Sabbu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve my problem using the gems instead of using gulp task.I am posting the answer here so that it may help others if they are looking the thing that I achieved using the rails gem.Here is the link of the gems:

https://github.com/tyronewilson/protractor-rails

Thanks
Sabbu